# Multiple "using tensorflow backend" messages flood the output while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When my model is trained with `model.fit_generator()` there are multiple "Using Tensorflow backend." messages flooding the output and breaking the training progress bar.

Before that I used `model.fit()`, and there was no message flood, it only printed that message once before the training. But I had to reorganize towards `model.fit_generator()` because my memory wasn't enough for my datasets. Now the output is flooded with these messages.

I am wondering, what's going on and what's the most correct way to prevent the flood. It breaks their own progress bar, which does not seem like expected behavior. Does it have anything to do with multiprocessing?

Here is how I run the training:

```
        history = model.fit_generator(
            generator=gen_training,
            validation_data=gen_validation,
            use_multiprocessing=True,
            workers=2,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint]
        )
```

Googling the problem suggested ways to suppress this message when keras is imported. But I don't even have a direct `import keras` line, instead I import from a lot of sub modules:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, CuDNNLSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Besides, the message appears during execution multiple times (about 20), i.e. not coming from my imports, but probably keras is instantiated multiple times during training for some reason?

- Keras: 2.2.4
- Tensorflow: 1.14.0
- Python: 3.7.3
- GPU is used

Comment: Please make a self-containing example that reproduces the problem, because I haven't seen this problem at all.

Comment: Eventually I switched to `use_multiprocessing=False` because it also caused a Broken Pipe error in the middle of a long training. The message flood is gone. Will stick to this for now, as feeding the data is not my performance bottleneck right now.